# New to Linear Algebra and OpenGL. Once you have a matrix of transformations, how do you draw them using openGL?

Tags: math, opengl, graphics, matrix, linear-algebra

I was looking at examples of being able to represent transformations using a matrix instead of the built in functions. I want to learn more about the low level functions WITHOUT using any of opengl's matrix or transform functions

Say I have a matrix class:
class Matrix
{
public:
    float data [ 3 ] [ 3 ];

```
Matrix ( void )
{
    int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
        {
            data [ i ] [ j ] = 0;
        }sa
    }
}
};
```

Example function:

```
Matrix scale ( Pt p, float alpha )
{
    Matrix rvalue;


        rvalue.data[0][0] = alpha;
        rvalue.data[0][1] = 0;
        rvalue.data[0][2] = (1-alpha)*p.x;

        rvalue.data[1][0] = 0;
        rvalue.data[1][1] = alpha;
        rvalue.data[1][2] = (1-alpha)*p.y;


        rvalue.data[2][0] = 0;
        rvalue.data[2][1] = 0;
        rvalue.data[2][2] = 1;


    return rvalue;
}
```

How would I apply those transformations using opengl? I'm not where where to start. Is there a function that cane take a 3x3 matrix and load it in?

Comment: Why are you using `alpha` in your matrix transformation?  That's more commonly seen in color blending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want one of `glLoadMatrix` or `glMultMatrix`. They take column-major 4x4 matrices so you'll want to write a shim like:

```
GLfloat matrix[16];

matrix[0] = data[0][0];
matrix[1] = data[0][1];
matrix[2] = data[0][2];
matrix[3] = 0.0f;

matrix[4] = data[1][0];
matrix[5] = data[1][1];
matrix[6] = data[1][2];
matrix[7] = 0.0f;

matrix[8] = data[2][0];
matrix[9] = data[2][1];
matrix[10] = data[2][2];
matrix[11] = 0.0f;

matrix[12] = 0.0f;
matrix[13] = 0.0f;
matrix[14] = 0.0f;
matrix[15] = 1.0f;

glLoadMatrixf(matrix);
```

So I've just padded out your data with the relevant parts of the identity matrix.

Comment: See my https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h for a ready to use set of linear algebra primitives. Note that this library is targeted toward a C audience and not optimized! The purpose of this library is mostly to have a Quick and Dirty drop in with an easy to understand structure. It's more than fast enough for use with typical OpenGL tasks, but I'd not use it for numerical simulation.

Answer (score 1):

You mean [`glLoadMatrix`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml)?

Really, I think you could have guessed that name.

---

Now, this is a deprecated function in OpenGL 3+.  Instead you would use [`glUniformMatrix3fv`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glUniformMatrix) to load the transformation into a uniform, where you could retrieve it in your shader and apply it using matrix multiply.